# Ubuntu 18.04 and Rainlendar 2 install problem

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

I can't install Rainlendar 2 on my Ubuntu 18.04, I found this solution for 16.04 ([Unable To Install Rainlendar2 For Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (32 & 64 Bit)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812753/unable-to-install-rainlendar2-for-ubuntu-16-04-lts-32-64-bit)), followed it, seems to work, but after install, there's no Rainlendar in my Show Apps, so I'm not sure what went wrong. When I issued `sudo dpkg -i rainlendar2-pro_2.12.2.b138-1_amd64.deb`, I got this:

```
Selecting previously unselected package rainlendar2-pro.
(Reading database ... 190677 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack rainlendar2-pro_2.12.2.b138-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rainlendar2-pro (2.12.2.b138-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rainlendar2-pro:
 rainlendar2-pro depends on libpng12-0; however:
  Package libpng12-0 is not installed.
 rainlendar2-pro depends on tofrodos; however:
  Package tofrodos is not installed.
 rainlendar2-pro depends on libjpeg62; however:
  Package libjpeg62 is not installed.
 rainlendar2-pro depends on libwebkitgtk-1.0-0; however:
  Package libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package rainlendar2-pro (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rainlendar2-pro
```

I got this after issuing this command in terminal `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  rainlendar2-pro
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 20.5 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 191316 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing rainlendar2-pro (2.12.2.b138-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1) ...
```

What I'm doing wrong? After the last command it just removed Rainlendar and not installing dependencies as stated in the original post? TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install the deb-package of Rainlendar Pro with `apt-get install`, it will satisfy all dependencies:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://www.rainlendar.net/download/rainlendar2-pro_2.14.2.b157-1_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt-get install ./rainlendar2-pro_2.14.2.b157-1_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'rainlendar2-pro' instead of './rainlendar2-pro_2.14.2.b157-1_amd64.deb'
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-30 linux-headers-4.15.0-30-generic linux-image-4.15.0-30-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-30-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-30-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libpango1.0-0 libpangox-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libpango1.0-0 libpangox-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 rainlendar2-pro
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 9 916 kB/31,1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 63,3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
...

$ rainlendar2
```

I tested its installation on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

[image: rainlendar2 on Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS]

As the result you will have calendar, todo and tasks widgets / gadgets / screenlets on top of the desktop.

---

If you want to install Rainlendar Lite version, then use

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://www.rainlendar.net/download/rainlendar2-lite_2.14.2.b157-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./rainlendar2-lite_2.14.2.b157-1_amd64.deb
```

I tested it on default Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with GNOME sHell, it placed widgets to desktop, but does not show icon in the tray:

[image: Rainlendar Lite on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS]

Comment: Thanks so much N0rbert for helping me out, I was banging my head trying to figure out what went wrong. Thanks for spending your time to test it and explaining.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu 19.04. I still get: The following packages have umet depedencies: rainlendar2-pro : Depends: libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 but it is not installable. E: Unable to correct problems, you have broken packages.

Comment: At least for me I needed to separately download and install the following from pkgs.org (I selected the debian stretch version): libicu57_57.1-6+deb9u2_amd64.deb,  libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3_amd64.deb, libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.1-2_amd64.deb, libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3_amd64.deb. After doing that I could get rainlendar to install.